# Order By Date Time breaks in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

The following  details the error I am getting
The Student Class

```
public class Student () {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Student(int id IEnumerable<StudentOwner> owner) {
         _owners = owners != null ? owners.ToList() : new List<StudentOwner>();
    }
    private List<StudentOwner> _owners;
}
```

The StudentDetailsClass

```
public class StudentDetails () {
    pubiic int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public int StudentRef {get; set; }

}
```

A selection of the offending code for the query is as follows, it works if you order by s.ID

```
  baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(
              o => s.StudentDetails
                   .OrderByDescending(s => **s.UpdateDate**).First().StudentRef
                == StudentSearchParams.StudentRef;
```

The following error occurs, yet if you do order by Id it works but that does not produce the required result. Any ideas ???

```
 .OrderByDescending(s1 => s1.UpdateDate)' could not be translated. 
 Additional information: Translation of member 'UpdateDate' on entity type 'StudentDetails' failed. 
 This commonly occurs when the specified member is unmapped. Either rewrite the query in a form 
 that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 
 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: You have more `(` than `)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you

> Translation of member 'UpdateDate' on entity type 'StudentDetails' failed.
> This commonly occurs when the specified member is **unmapped**

And what you have is

```cs
public class StudentDetails
{
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; }
}
```

i.e. *get only* property (no setter). And [by EF Core conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#included-and-excluded-properties)

> By convention, all public properties with a getter and a setter will be included in the model.

in other words, properties w/o a setter are ignored (not included, unmapped).

Append `set;` after `get;` and the problem will be gone.

Comment: thank you so much, that makes perfect sence, I just couldnt see the wood from the trees !!